# cursor.readConcern is not a function

Tags: mongodb

```
module.exports.getHotelName = function(callback){

    cursor = Hotel.collection.find({});

    cursor.readConcern('local');
}
```

I already have collection named `'hotels'`.
The Hotel is indicates the hotels correctly.
I want get the all documents in Hotel but when I using `cursor.readConcern('local')` I get error message

```
'TypeError: cursor.readConcern is not a function'.
```

Someone who know this, please answer my question.

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I am using MongoDB version 3.4.6

Comment: What MongoDB client module are you using (i.e. what did you install with `npm install ...`). Check to see cursor is actually a promise by either `cursor instanceof Promise` or by the existence of a `cursor.then` method.

Comment: There is no such method as `readConcern()` for a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html). What do you think you are trying to set? What are you even trying to do? Or are you just following an incorrect example?

Comment: @NeilLunn "New in version 3.2" https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.readConcern/

Comment: @AtesGoral Who cares mongo shell methods there are? I'm actually pointing to the nodejs driver documentation that the code is actually written for. Seems you were not paying attention to that part.

Comment: It's the error of mongodb version.
thanks AtesGoral and NeilLunn